# Can I create fields during normalisation

Tags: database, database-normalization

Just had a quick question:

Can I create fields during the normalisation process?

For example if I was normalising from a form, which was a doctors registration form, could I create a primary key as Patient_ID, instead of having to use Patient_Name as this wouldn't be a unique field...

Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, you may. This is a very common thing to do.

Comment: In some cases, like normalizing set-valued attributes which are also part of a candidate key, a surrogate key needs to be introduced. However, in most cases surrogate keys have nothing to do with normalization. If it's for school, don't introduce surrogate keys except when necessary. In the field, it's more common, and in your example, a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will only use it if necessary :)

Comment: If your new design doesn't tell you the same thing about a given situation as your old design then the new is not a "normalization" of the old. If you are adding ids because your old design couldn't always distinguish between people and you need a design that can then you're not normalizing, you're replacing a inappropriate design by an appropriate one. PS "Normalizing" in the sense of moving to higher normal forms never introduces new attribute names.

Answer (score 1):

You can create attributes any time you want to. But creating new attributes has *nothing* to do with normalization. When you create new attributes, you also create new functional dependencies.  Keep that in mind.

Conceptually, normalization is one step in designing a database. It happens *after* you decide what attributes to store in your database, and *after* you've determined all their functional dependencies.

Normalization decomposes a relation by taking proper subsets of it. Proper subsets can't contain attributes that weren't there to start with.